# Add Button to LinearLayout - setText gives null

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a button programmatically and add it to a LinearLayout.

I have the following code, and although all seems to work fine, I end up with a button with no text.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < seed.dealer.size(); i++)
    {
        Button dealer = new Button(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 40);
        params.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

        dealer.setLayoutParams(params);
        dealer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_green);
        dealer.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.BOLD));
        dealer.setTextSize(22);
        dealer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0F0"));

        dealer.setText(seed.dealer.get(i).name);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        float logicalDensity = metrics.density;

        int px = (int) (200 * logicalDensity + 0.5);
        dealer.setMinWidth(px);

        px = (int) (350 * logicalDensity + 0.5);
        dealer.setMaxWidth(px);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dealerContainer);
        ll.addView(dealer);
    }
```

Comment: You need to add more context to this snippet. Are you calling this inside an activity? Do the other attributes have any effect on the button (the size, the background)? Have you tried this without looping (and with a hard coded string)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think I know what might be wrong now. This is called within an activity yes, but it called on the onResume() method of the fragment that resides within the activity. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with this line :

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 40);`

I had to convert height to dp because the button height was so small that made the it look like there was no text.

Answer (score 1):

first check `seed.dealer.get(i).name` is giving a valid String (not `null` and not empty). if it is giving a valid String, I think the problem is with text color of a button (`Color.parseColor("#F0F0F0")` is giving color something like transparent(exactly I have not tested)). so try changing text color to other color like `Color.BLACK` or `Color.RED` something like...

Comment: `seed.dealer.get(i).name` does return a valid string. I tried changing the color. Didn't work.

Comment: F0F0F0 is a gray color.

Comment: change dealer.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0F0")) to dealer.setTextColor(0xFFF0F0F0) and try once...

Comment: once consider Amokrane Chentir comment... and is your buttons are adding to layout? are they visble(atleast Buttons background if not text))?

Comment: I can see the green button, correctly placed with correct width. height however is very small because of missing text ( WRAP_CONTENT ). However, when debugging I can see the text being correctly set.

Comment: @GopalRao I think the problem might be that all this code is called in the onResume of the fragment.